# Back-Connect Server and SMTP Troubles

Tags: c#, sockets, smtp, reverse-proxy

I don't understand whats the problem on this type of error.
I have a Back-Connect Servers (type Socks4/5 or HTTP). I use a server to connect to one of the remote PC. For that I open a TCP-Connection to one of this Server (serverip:randport).

```
// create an instance of the client proxy factory
            ProxyClientFactory factory = new ProxyClientFactory();

            ProxyHost = "string:serverIP";
            ProxyPort = int:serverPort;

            proxy = factory.CreateProxyClient(proxyType, ProxyHost, ProxyPort);
            try
            { .. }
```

I use a Starksoft SOCKS and HTTP Proxy Component v1.0.130.0 for that factory.

And now the problem:
to send a Email I use a RFC821 to configure the communication on the remote PC.
This is the same deal if y have on localhost opened 25 port by your provider.

```
            snd("HELO", true);
            snd("MAIL FROM:" + sender, true);
            snd("RCPT TO:" + recipient, true);
            snd("DATA", true);
            snd("From: " + sender);
            snd("To: " + recipient);
            snd("Subject: " + subject);
            snd("");
            snd(messagebody);
            snd(".", true);
            snd("QUIT", true);
```

and I get a error on this row

```
private bool snd(string buffer, bool getresponse)
        {
            this.response = "";
            NetworkStream stream = this.GetStream();
            Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(buffer + crlf);
            if (!stream.CanWrite) { return false; }
            try
            {
                stream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
            }
```

[image: Screen Nr1]
+$exception {"Unable to write data to the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine."}   System.Exception {System.IO.IOException}

and console write this on exception
[image: Screen Nr2in]

**How I do a reverse backconnect connections???**

The answer is to use an intermediary server. Then the script will look like this:

1. There is an intermediate server that is no problem to open a port, for example, 65 080 for the server and 80 clients
2. There is a server (HTTP), which can not open the port, but he knows the address of an intermediate server, and the "server" port 65080. It connects to an intermediate server connection 1.
3. There is a regular client, such as the browser
4. The client connects to an intermediate server on port 80 connections 2, and makes a request
5. Further, the intermediate server reports directly to the Executive request that is connected to port 65 080 Compound 1, which asks, and it would have to work off-
6. The server receives the request, the server connects to another intermediate compound 3, ask the middleware server request, fulfills it, and sends a response to a staging server
7. The intermediate server forwards the response from the server (from compound 3) to the client (for compound 2)
8. The client terminates the connection

### **So where did I go wrong?**